# Force CMake to build in release mode with symbols

Tags: ios, cmake

I’ve inherited a large iOS project that is built with CMake, and a fair amount of python scripts driving the cmake process. It’s a fairly complex beast and will take some time for me to understand all of the moving parts.

The only CMake build that works is Release - Debug, RelWithDebInfo and MinSizeRel all cause the app to crash on launch. Debugging this has so far proven to be a time-sink.

I’d like to short circuit the process and simply build in Release and not strip symbols. Any suggestions how to go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Add `-g` or whatever you want to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`.

Maybe it gets overwritten, then have a look for these lines in CMake code similar to

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall")
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Wall")

or in your Python scripts

-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=..
   -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=..